# What information does Result contain when using FOP and XSL-FO, and how can I use it?

Tags: java, xslt, xsl-fo

I am using Apache FOP in conjunction with XSL-FO to convert XML into a formatted PDF. Right now I have the following method in Java (ignore the fact that the method is not returning a boolean for now):

```
public boolean Transform() throws TransformerException, FOPException
{
  Transformer lTransformer;
  java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream lOutStream = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();

  FopFactory lFopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance();
  FOUserAgent lFOAgent = lFopFactory.newFOUserAgent();

  lTransformer = getTransformer(mXsltSource); // returns a new Transformer
  Fop fop = lFopFactory.newFop(mMimeOut, lFOAgent, lOutStream);
  Result res = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());

  lTransformer.transform(mSource, res); // transforms xml source to formatted XSL-FO transform
}
```

However, I am unsure of how to use "res" to make sure that the "lTransformer.transform(StreamSource, Result)" method executed correctly (I am assuming that is the purpose of the Result object). I have looked at the javadocs for the transform method, Result class, and SAXResult class, but these have not yielded much help. Can anybody offer some insight into this?

TL;DR; **What is the purpose of passing a Result in *javax.xml.transform.Transformer.transform(StreamSource, Result)*, and how can I use this to check that the operation completed successfully?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of the transform is written to that Result object.  If you look at the chain of objects that go into creating the `Result` object, the output stream you've specified is ultimately where the result is written (you passed a `ByteArrayOutputStream` into `FopFactory.newFop()`, and then pass the `Fop` handler into the `Result` - the output stream is the ultimate destination of your xsl transformation.

Pass in a `FileOutputStream` pointing to a file on your disk somewhere instead of the `ByteArrayOutputStream`, and after the transformation (if everything worked), the file should be a PDF you can view.

Comment: ahh okay, i understand how it works now. I was expecting result to be something like "Result.OK", or "Result.SomeErrorOccurredDuringTransform", etc.